# In Python 2.7, "Import Error No module named io" after installing wq.io

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror

In python, I have installed the module `wq.io`.

How come when I type `import wq.io` in the Python console, it says the following error:

`ImportError: No module named io`

When I type `import wq` or `import io`, the Python console has no import errors.

Can anyone explain the discrepancies?

Comment: Are you positive it's installed? Try re-installing and verify you meet all of its dependencies. I just tried multiple variations of the import statement as well as usage and I saw no issues at all using 2.7 which leads me to believe you may be missing something. Perhaps you could provide us with your code as well that way we can see if you're importing it wrong?

Comment: Same as @Afflicted. It came as part of `pip install wq`, I didn't have to `pip install wq.io` separately as the documentation seems to claim.